# I'm having a problem with @Scheduled and spring boot. A job after finished happens to run again sometimes after some minutes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

I'm having a problem with @Scheduled and spring boot in a job that have to be executed each hour in the day, but the job is being executed when he shouldn't.

For instance... The job has to be executed each hour 00:00:00:000, 01:00:00:000, 02:00:00:000 and so on ... but sometimes, it's not a pattern, happens to be executed again after some minutes for another pod on k8s. Cronjob time is (0 0 * * * ?) every hour.

lock settings
defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT40S",
defaultLockAtLeastFor = "PT20S"

job executation logs
[image]

There's a scheduller table in the DB to control the lock, to avoid two pods to execute at the same cronjob time.

anyone knows why this kind of behaviour happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use something like quartz to do the scheduling/launching which has support for using 1 instance of a job. Don't try to write your own scheduling/locking mechanism.

Comment: At the first I was going to use quartz, but for what I know it is possible to control jobs execution trhough a table in the database with shedlock. That's how I am controlling the execution of the job, seems fine the lock mechanism (cronjob timestamp). But this behaviour of executing outside of the determined time stipulated  in the cronjob is what makes me intrigued about it.

Comment: Shedlock only locks for a certain time not the whole processing time so it is just kind-of a solution. Whereas quartz does it really on a job instance.